# admin endpoint for identity service not found

Tags: identity, openstack, keystone

I made a mistake and delete the keystone identity endpoints, and when I want to create the endpoints again I receive this error:

```
admin endpoint for identity service not found
```

Also I can't execute other commands of keystone.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do something similar and fixed it with these commands:

```
keystone-manage fernet_setup --keystone-user keystone --keystone-group keystone

keystone-manage credential_setup --keystone-user keystone --keystone-group keystone

keystone-manage bootstrap --bootstrap-password ADMIN_PASS --bootstrap-admin-url http://example.com:35357/v3/ --bootstrap-internal-url http://example.com:35357/v3/ --bootstrap-public-url http://example.com:35357/v3/ --bootstrap-region-id RegionOne
```

Based on the Docs at http://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-rdo/keystone.html